# ExtJS Content sliding/scrolling like Sencha Touch (ExtJS Drag Scroll)

Tags: extjs, scroll, sliding

How can I achieve effect of sliding/scrolling content of Ext.panel.Panel/Ext.view.View or any other container like in mobile applications or Sencha Touch?

Something like drag scroll with a mouse (like PDF documents).

Can someone give me any hint, code snippet, or just tell me where to start?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RahulSingla integrated iScroll with extjs to achieve this functionality [here](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/extjs-and-iscroll-scrolling-ext-containers-on-touch-devices-ipad-iphone-etc-using-iscro). It's with extjs3 however. As of today, I need this same thing in extjs4 for a grid panel. So I will try something along these lines but with extjs scroll methods instead of iScroll. I'll update if I get anything working.

**UPDATE:**

Done. (for what I needed) It turns out to be pretty straightforward to add drag scrolling from a listener on the grid panel, wasn't much coding needed:

```
listeners: {
    'itemmousedown': function(view, rec, item, idx, event) {

        var startX = event.getX();
        var startY = event.getY();

        var grid = view.up('gridpanel');
        var div = grid.getEl();
        var body = Ext.getBody();

        body.setStyle('cursor','-moz-grabbing'); //doesn't work in 4.0.7+

        div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            x = e.getX(), y = e.getY()
            grid.scrollByDeltaX(startX - x);
            grid.scrollByDeltaY(startY - y);
            startX = x
            startY = y
        });

        body.on('mouseup', function(e){
            body.setStyle('cursor','default'); //doesn't work in 4.0.7+
            div.removeAllListeners();
            body.removeAllListeners();
        });

        body.on('mouseleave', function(e, tgt){
            body.setStyle('cursor','default'); //doesn't work in 4.0.7+
            div.removeAllListeners();
            body.removeAllListeners();
        });
    }
}
```

I've only tested this on FF because that is all we use on our intranet. I'm not sure if IE has the mousemove event `.getX()` or `.getY()` functions so that might need to be tweaked.

For other panels (something other than a grid panel) you could probably just replace the `itemmousedown` listener with just a `mousedown` listener to have the same functionality.

Comment: thanks, but example You provided works in Sencha Touch, not ExtJS

Comment: but anyway, that post led me to the following
[LINK](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/extjs-and-iscroll-scrolling-ext-containers-on-touch-devices-ipad-iphone-etc-using-iscro)

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're going for now, after I wanted to implement the same thing for a grid. DRAG SCROLL (like pdf documents). I fixed the link. Did you have any luck with this iScroll integration? I was going to try overriding my panel with the ExtJS methods otherwise. I'll post what I come up with if I have any luck.